# Как посчитать общее количество за определенную дату?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Привет, ребятки! Подскажите, как посчитать общее количество продаж за определенную дату? Скачал плагин xCharts для реализации графика. Основная часть:

```
$start = $_GET['start'];  
$end = $_GET['end'];  
$data = array();

// Select the results with Idiorm

  $results = ORM::for_table('Configuration')  
  ->where_gte('Date', $start)  
  ->where_lte('Date', $end)  
  ->order_by_desc('Date')  
  ->find_array();

// Build a new array with the data  

foreach ($results as $key => $value) {  
$data[$key]['label'] = $value['Date'];  
$data[$key]['value'] = $sum; - //тут должно выводиться общее количество  проданных товаров за дату.
}

echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Покажу базу: как видно, за 13 число было 4 продажи, за 14 - одна. Вот я хочу сделать так, чтобы в графике отображалось, что за 13 число было 4 продажи. Как это сделать?
[prntscr.com/7ixrnw](http://prntscr.com/7ixrnw)

Comment: Где код javascript? Php к вашему вопросу почти никакого отношения не имеет. И не мешало бы посмотреть примеры к xCharts

Comment: Вот отсюда я взял информацию -- http://sitear.ru/material/jquery-xcharts-grafiki-sozdayte-krasivye-grafiki

Comment: Ну а что конкретно не получается?

Comment: как видите, у меня не такая база. Мне надо как-то сложить все продажи за определенную дату в одну(типа как sales_data). Вы можете увидеть, что в моей таблице за 13 число было 4 продажи. Вот мне как раз и надо отобразить, что за 13 число значение было равное 4. Как это сделатЬ? Я не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, правильно ли я понял суть вопроса, но, можно в цикле подсчитать количество продаж, например, так:

```
$start = $_GET['start'];  
$end = $_GET['end'];  
$data = array();

// Select the results with Idiorm

  $results = ORM::for_table('Configuration')  
  ->where_gte('Date', $start)  
  ->where_lte('Date', $end)  
  ->order_by_desc('Date')  
  ->find_array();

$tmp = array();
foreach ($results as $value) {  
  $tmp[$value['Date']]['count'] += 1;
  $tmp[$value['Date']]['Sellers'] .= ' '.$value['Seller'];
}

// Build a new array with the data  

foreach ($results as $key => $value) {  
   $data[$key]['label'] = $value['Date'];  
   $data[$key]['value'] = $tmp[$value['Date']]['count']; 
   $data[$key]['Sellers'] = $tmp[$value['Date']]['Sellers']; 
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Еще раз: есть колонка с датами в таблице, она называется Date. В эту колонку(столбец) вносится дата, когда формируется заказ. Если количество заказов в день было 10, то в базу занесется 10 записей, у которых дата будет, к примеру, 10/10/2015. Вся суть в том, чтобы на графике было показано, что 10/10/2015 было оформлено 10 заказов. В другой день - совсем другое число. Считайте, тоже самое как и в примере http://sitear.ru/material/jquery-xcharts-grafiki-sozdayte-krasivye-grafiki в столбце sales_order. Только там вручную записано общее кол-во.
Ваш вариант не работает - http://prntscr.com/7jb03q

Comment: Писал таким образом:
 // Build a new array with the data
 foreach ($results as $key => $value) {   
  $data[$key]['label'] = $value['Date'];   
  $data[$key]['value'] = $data[$value['Date']] += 1;   

 }

Comment: Идёт выборка из базы данных всех заказов с начальной и конечной датой. Одна строка выборки = 1 заказ. Нужно узнать количество заказов по общей дате. То есть, сколько заказов было сделано за конкретное число. Именно это я и написал. Изменил код в ответе для большего понимания того, что я хотел сказать...

Comment: Написал как у вас - http://prntscr.com/7jbehu 
Выводит пустой график

Comment: Так первый блок так же нужно вставить )). Откуда же взяться массиву $tmp? )

Comment: Первый блок? Я его вставил. На скрине показано
 foreach ($results as $value) {  
   $tmp[$value['Date']] += 1;
 }

Comment: Так его же нужно вставлять после запроса в БД )

Comment: Да, уже сделал) Получается вот такое - http://prntscr.com/7jbh8a 
Можно как-то шаг в 0,5 изменить?

Comment: Я сейчас подправил код в ответе, чтобы более понятно выглядел. Я так понял, ответ подходит?

Comment: А зачем шаг в 0,5? Разве может быть 0,5 или полтора заказа в день?

Comment: Да, спасибо вам огромное. Код и ответ подходят, но хотелось бы, чтобы шага в 0.5 не было( Только 1, 2, 3 и т.д. Сейчас показывается 1, 1.5, 2...

Comment: За вывода значений 0,5 отвечает уже не php скрипт, а, видимо js. 0,5 заказа не может быть. Эти полуторные цифры нужно убрать в конструкторе графика.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Еще 1 вопрос: как можно отобразить, что эти все заказы оформил какой-то определенный менеджер? Допустим, навести на точку(дату) и будет отображаться логин менеджера

Comment: На графике выводится количество заказов в определённый день. Если заказов несколько и их оформляли разные менеджеры, логин которых которых сохранён в БД для каждого заказа, то можно составить список этих менеджеров и выводить этот список на графике. Список можно добавить в массив.

Comment: Например: `$data[$key]['manager'] .= ' '.$value['loginManager'];  `

Comment: Это ведь не так делается? http://prntscr.com/7jbrmy

Comment: Там в коде ошибки есть... Я подправил ответ, где теперь в массив $data должны добавляться менеджеры. Вообще, сам массив не очень удачный для вывода данных для подобного графика. Но я уже подстраиваюсь под имеющийся код, чтобы ещё не пришлось переписывать js код подстановки значений в график. В любом случае, через json будут передаваться менеджеры для каждой даты. Если их больше одного, то будут отображаться списком через пробел. Но передать данные в массиве не достаточно. Ещё нужно писать код для отображения их на графике...

Comment: Проверил ваш код измененный. Но только не отображаются менеджеры. Не связано ли это с тем, что в переменной $results выбираются данные из столбца Date, а менеджера надо взять со столбца Seller?

Comment: Я и беру данные из столбца "Seller". Я так понимаю, в запросе в базу данных "Configuration" идёт выборка по всем столбцам из БД. Зачем Вы в своём коде дублировали повторно запрос, только делали сортировку по Saller не понятно. Достаточно одного запроса. Да и где должны отображаться эти Saller(ы) ? Я же выше написал, что они только передаются в массиве $data. Должны передаваться. У меня нет полного кода и базы данных под рукой, чтобы это проверить ). По логике - передаются. Далее нужно писать javascript код, который будет подключать всё это дело к графику...

Comment: Должны были отображаться сбоку(возле точки или при наведении на нее), чтобы посмотреть, кто оформил заказ. Но лучше сделаю или как-то постараюсь сделать второй график, где надо будет выбрать из списка менеджеров логин нужного, а затем формировать график. Исходя из вашего примера ничего же не измениться, если я захочу так сделать?

Comment: Из написанного сложно понять, какими будут Ваши дальнейшие действия по созданию графика. Учитывая связку php, sql, js, html, чтобы полностью увидеть картину, мне нужно будет установить на локальный хостинг целиком весь Ваш сайт, а потом уже разбираться, что к чему ). Пробуйте делать. Если долго мучиться, то что-нибудь точно получится. Если нужно быстрее, то тогда стоит задуматься о найме того, кто это сделает за Вас. Если выберите быстрый, но финансово-затратный путь, то я к Вашим услугам ).

Comment: Ок. Но сначала попробуйте сделать сами ).

Comment: Хорошо, постараюсь. Еще раз спасибо за помощь с этой проблемкой для меня)